# Material design paginator doesn't work with tables dynamically generated

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-paginator

I am trying to generate multiple tables with multiple columns using material table and it worked correctly.
But the problem arises when paging the results of each table.
It seems that it does not take the reference of each table, then all the paginators are set to 0.

Here is my code in stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-k8qfd3?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: can you please show me the code?

Comment: Maybe this is how stackblitz works but my question is how come all the code is pre-compiled and not in the original typescript format?

Comment: please check you are giving the mat-paginator [length]="100"   table data length

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-k8qfd3?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Check line 118 as well in app.component.ts. this.paginator is always undefined.

Comment: @Mickers no, because I have another page works fine with one table. It has the same initialization of paginator

`export class CompanyComponent implements OnInit {

  displayedColumns: string[] = ['name', 'description', 'actions'];

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
  datasource = new MatTableDataSource<CompanyModel>();

....
    this.companyService.getCompanies().then( (data:any) => {

      this.datasource.data = data;
      this.datasource.paginator = this.paginator;
      this.datasource.sort = this.sort;`

Answer (score 0):

try this set the pagination length in the ngAfterViewInit hook.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {

this.paginationLength = this.tableData.length;

}
```

in the template:

```
<mat-paginator [length]="paginationLength"
              [pageSize]="10"
              [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]">
</mat-paginator>
```

Comment: it will not work, because tableData is generated dynamically inside the run() method inside a for loop. see line 119